# Selecting specific newly appended node copy for event jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, events

I am switching to jQuery, due to the complicated syntax of Javascript. I wrote a JQ script to copy an and append a div with its event listeners. It should open content of a button and be able to delete that same button with its content. However, opening the content does so for all the copied elements and deleting the div does so only with the top div. Can anybody please help with this issue?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test2").click(function() {
    $("#samplesinfo").clone(true).insertAfter("#paste");
  });
  $(".accordion").click(function() {
    $(".panel").toggle();
  });
  $(".delbtn").click(function() {
    $("#samplesinfo").remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.close {
  float: right;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<h2>Example</h2>
<button class="test2">ADD</button>

<div id="samplesinfo">
  <div class="test">
    <button class="delbtn" id="delbtn" style="float: right;">Delete</button>
    <button id="sample" class="accordion" style="float: left;">Button</button>
    <div id="usrInput" class="panel">
      <input type="text" name="test">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="paste">
</div>
```

Also, each button contains user input option. Deleting the div should be done with the specific user input that is no longer needed. For example if you input "hello" into the third copied element and press the delete button, it should only delete the element which said "hello" and not from the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the other answer, when you "Add", it copies the first one, including the `input` content if you typed in it.

I often like to use hidden templates, so here is what I suggest you:

- Start with only one element with `class="hidden"`. This is the "template".
- When you click <kbd>Add</kbd>, the "template" will be copied, made visible, and appended after your last element.
- On load, we trigger the `click` event to start with one visible element.
- As you should avoid inline styling, I also moved that to the CSS.

Working snippet:

```js
var index = 0;
$(".test2").click(function() {
  var element = $(".samplesinfo.hidden").clone(true);
  element.removeClass('hidden').insertAfter(".samplesinfo:last");
  element.find('.delbtn').text('Delete ' + ++index);
});

$(".accordion").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".panel").toggle();
});

$(".delbtn").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".samplesinfo").remove();
});

// Trigger click on load
$(".test2").trigger('click');
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}

.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  float: left;
}

.delbtn {
  float: right;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<h2>Example</h2>
<button class="test2">ADD</button>

<div class="samplesinfo hidden">
  <div class="test">
    <button class="delbtn">Delete</button>
    <button class="accordion">Button</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <input type="text" name="test">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that `id`s must be unique.
`this` is a powerful keyword when you want to target an element relative to the current one (the one on which you triggered en event).

⋅
⋅
⋅

And here is a JavaScript version…

Event listeners are not copied with JavaScript, so we need to call a function each time we add a new element!…

Snippet:

```js
var index = 0;
var template = document.querySelector(".samplesinfo.hidden");

document.querySelector(".test2").onclick = function() {
  var element = template.cloneNode(true);
  element.classList.remove('hidden');
  element.querySelector('.delbtn').innerText = 'Delete ' + ++index;
  var samples = document.querySelectorAll(".samplesinfo");
  var last = samples[samples.length - 1];
  last.parentNode.insertBefore(element, last.nextSibling);
  refresh_listeners();  
}

// Event listeners are not copied with JavaScript, so we need to call this function each time we add a new element!…
function refresh_listeners() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".accordion").forEach(function(elm) {
    elm.onclick = function() {
      elm.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hidden");
    }
  });
  document.querySelectorAll(".delbtn").forEach(function(elm) {
    elm.onclick = function() {
      elm.closest(".samplesinfo").outerHTML = '';
    }
  });
}

// Trigger click
document.querySelector(".test2").click();
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  float: left;
}

.delbtn {
  float: right;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<h2>Example</h2>
<button class="test2">ADD</button>

<div class="samplesinfo hidden">
  <div class="test">
    <button class="delbtn">Delete</button>
    <button class="accordion">Button</button>
    <div class="panel hidden">
      <input type="text" name="test">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I apply this to my script, the Add button does not work. Should I still include the $(document).ready(function() { ?

Comment: @RoelofCoertze It depends on where you put your script. If it's before the end of the `</body>`, you need to add it. If it's after, it's not necessary. I removed it because it isn't necessary in the snippet. So, yep, you may need to add it, depending of where is your code. :)

Comment: Also, the continuous numbering now starts at 2 instead of 1. Another concern is that in my actual program, the element is appended from the template already open when it should be closed. By the way, this method of yours is very very helpful and makes sense when you have multiple user input.

Comment: @RoelofCoertze I noted that the inputs are kind of crazy when you toggle them. If you display only the third one, it appears on the first, etc…

Comment: @RoelofCoertze The numbering is complicated to do, too. In the answer you accepted, if you delete a one in the middle and add another one, it takes a number already used. That's also one of the reason why I removed it. And also because I didn't know if it was useful, would you want me to add it back? (With a -1 offset, the numbering will start at 0 on the hidden template.)

Comment: Yes I noticed this as well, however I do not see what you mean with the toggle of the inputs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172770/discussion-between-takit-isy-and-roelof-coertze).

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers in HTML must be **unique**, Here in example I have used CSS classes. You need to target element in current element i.e. `this` context

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test2").click(function() {
    var element = $(".samplesinfo:first").clone(true);
    
    element.insertAfter(".samplesinfo:last");

    //Get all delbtn
    var delbtns = $('.delbtn');

    //get last elements index
    var index = delbtns.index(delbtns.last()) + 1;

    //set Text
    element.find('.delbtn').text('Delete' + index)
  });
  
  $(".accordion").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".panel").toggle();
  });
  $(".delbtn").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".samplesinfo").remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.close {
  float: right;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<h2>Example</h2>
<button class="test2">ADD</button>

<div class="samplesinfo">
  <div class="test">
    <button class="delbtn" style="float: right;">Delete</button>
    <button id="sample" class="accordion" style="float: left;">Button</button>
    <div id="usrInput" class="panel">
      <input type="text" name="test">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="paste">
</div>
```

Comment: I actually tried using "this" but placed it incorrectly. Thank you so much! I have been struggling all day, first with JS but this is much simpler.

Comment: By the way, would you happen to know how I could continuously number the buttons as they are copied and appended? So button 1 would become button two once appended and so on...?

Comment: @RoelofCoertze, Updated code snippet (with inline comment)

Comment: Thank you so much!